# In Dependency Injection where is an object to be injected created?

Tags: dependency-injection

If it was created by the class that is injecting it into the object that uses it then isn't it just moving object creation one step up the stack? And wouldn't this mean that all objects needed by lower level classes would need to be passed through each object one at a time until it reached the object that needed it?

All objects and their dependencies could be set up at the very beginning, but wouldn't this dent performance as objects will be hanging around until needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is moving the object instantiation up the stack.  But it is moving it up the stack to a place where you can make a better decision as to which implementation to actually use.  If I want to replace my data access layer with a stubbed version to do performance testing of the business logic, I can without changing a single line of the business logic code.

There are may ways to inject your dependencies.  In my case, I use constructor injection everywhere.  Using this method, if a lower level class needs a dependency, it just puts the interface for that dependency in its constructor.  No need to pass from a class higher up in the stack.  If you need the same instance in both classes, then you should look at the lifestyle/scope of when registering your dependency into the container so that both classes happen to get passed the same instance.

Some DI implementations use lazy loading to instantiate their objects.  (i.e. it's not until the object is attempted to be used that it is actually instantiated)  Some do not.  Also, you would need quite the large dependency graph to make a dent in performance.  Keep your constructors simple and fast (a good practice anyway) and this will not be a problem, I assure you.  And DI containers are smart about releasing objects that are no longer in use (again, pay special attention to lifestyle/scope).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure what to think about that comment @Steve. (And the many up-votes on it.)  Was my answer confusing?  Any specific area need clarification?

Comment: +10 means that I completely agree with you and that I would have given 10 upvoted if I could.

Comment: Hah, wow.  I misread that thinking you had only replied with "....." and ten people had upvoted that reply.  Thanks for the support =).

Comment: Sorry, the dots were just to allow me to post the comment. The minimum is 15 characters :-)

Comment: Sorry, the dots were just to allow me to post the comment. The minimum is 15 characters :-)